# Dynamic pivot table with two id columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot

This is probably simple but I"m just not seeing it.  Your help is appreciated.  I have a table in MS SQLServer that looks like this

```
CustomerID     Time                         ItemID
1              2008-10-07 06:32:53:00.000    87432
1              2008-10-07 06:32:53:00.000    26413
2              2010-06-23 03:45:10:00.000    6312
2              2011-09-14 07:36:03:00.000    87432
2              2011-09-14 07:36:03:00.000    87432
```

I want to end up with a table that has each customer, the timestamp and the count of the items purchased during that timestamp, that looks like this

```
CustomerID    Time                         87432  26413   6312
1             2008-10-07 06:32:53:00.000    1       1       0
2             2010-06-23 03:45:10:00.000    0       0       1
2             2011-09-14 07:36:03:00.000    2       0       0
```

In the source table, the time and itemID are variable (and plentiful), so I'm thinking a dynamic pivot will do the trick.  Is this possible to do with pivot? If so, how?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server dynamic PIVOT query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with a dynamic [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).  This will count the number of `ItemId`s that you have for any number of `Time`s.

See a [SQL Fiddle with a Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d2fef/1). This demo leaves the time as a `varchar` as you stated they were. But this will work if the data is a `datetime` as well.

Since you want `time` in the final result, then when you `select` the columns, you will need to add the `time` column twice. I called it `time1` and `time`.  This allows you to aggregate on `time1` in the PIVOT and still have a `time` column for your final product.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(itemid) 
                    from temp
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT customerid, [time], ' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select customerid, [time] as time1, [time] as [time], itemid
                from temp
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                count([time1])
                for itemid in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

Comment: Sorry I didnt get why you did "[time] as time1" in the above query. Could u please throw some clue?

Comment: @JoeGJoseph I used `time` twice because the OP is asking for the `time` to be included in the final answer. When you perform a PIVOT, if you are aggregating on a field (in this case `time`) you cannot have that a a part of the final product.  So in order to get the `time` as a column in the result, you have to `select` it twice.

Comment: @bluefeet I didn't think about using time twice.  Thanks for the great answer and the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

### Approach #1 - **[Click here to see Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/47cbf/2)**

```
Declare @ItemIDs varchar(1000) = ''
Declare @Query varchar(8000) = ''

Select @ItemIDs = ISNULL(QuoteName(Convert(varchar, ItemID)) + ',', '') 
+ @ItemIDs 
From
(
    Select distinct ItemID From #MyTable
)K

SET @ItemIDs = SUBSTRING(@ItemIDs,0,len(@ItemIDs))

SET @Query = 'Select CustomerID, [Time],' + 
@ItemIDs + ' From 
(
    Select CustomerID, [Time], ItemID from #MyTable
)K Pivot
(
    count(ItemID) FOR ItemID IN (' + @ItemIDs + ')
) AS pvt'

EXEC(@Query)
```

---

### Approach #2  -   **[Click here to see Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/47cbf/1)**

```
Select CustomerID, [Time], [87432] as [87432], 
[26413] as [26413], [6312] as [6312] From 
(
    Select CustomerID, [Time], ItemID from #MyTable
)K Pivot
(
    count(ItemID) FOR ItemID IN ([87432] , [26413],[6312])
) AS pvt
```

Comment: thanks for the two approaches.  They explain what is going on in pivot tables very clearly, and I appreciate the demos. And approach # 1 is a great alternative to bluefeet's answer. Unfortunately I can only choose one answer, so just I picked the first one.